# save image to localstorage HTML after resize and show same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there a way to save a cropped image into local storage i am trying to store the cropped image to localstorage and fetch the same am unable to achieve after long research i have reached so far thill hear but the image is not saving to localstorage, and display the same after the image is saved in to local storage.

HTML:

```
 <img src="" id="image">
<input id="input" type="file" onchange="handleFiles()">
```

JS:

```
function handleFiles()
    {
        var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('input').files;
        var file = filesToUpload[0];

        // Create an image
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        // Create a file reader
        var reader = new FileReader();
        // Set the image once loaded into file reader
        reader.onload = function(e)
        {
            img.src = e.target.result;

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            //var canvas = $("<canvas>", {"id":"testing"})[0];
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;

            if (width > height) {
              if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                width = MAX_WIDTH;
              }
            } else {
              if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
              }
            }
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

            var  = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById('image').src = dataurl;     
        }

          localStorage.setItem("imgData", dataurl);
        // Load files into file reader
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);


        // Post the data
        /*
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("name", "some_filename.jpg");
        fd.append("image", dataurl);
        fd.append("info", "lah_de_dah");
        */
    }
```

Comment: Your code seems ok. You just need to put `localStorage.setItem("imgData", dataurl);` in your `reader.onload` callback. So it'll get something to put, in your current code, `dataurl` is undefined when you put.

Comment: @fuyushimoya thanks let me try

Comment: Another point. `var  = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` is is typo ? Should be `var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`.

Comment: @fuyushimoya don't work if u dont mind can u join me hear https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=NMq83vtcpq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the `dataurl` variable initialization?

This is the correct code:

```
function handleFiles() {
    var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('input').files;
    var file = filesToUpload[0];

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var dataurl;

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log("change");
        img.src = e.target.result;

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        if (width > height) {
            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                width = MAX_WIDTH;
            }
        } else {
            if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
            }
        }
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

        dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.getElementById('image').src = dataurl;     
    }

    localStorage.setItem("imgData", dataurl);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```